# "find /var/" vs "find /var/run/"

Tags: find

I am observing this odd behavior and found no explanation:

```
$ find /var/run/ -name reboot-required 2>/dev/null 
/var/run/reboot-required
```

BUT

```
$ find /var/ -name reboot-required 2>/dev/null
$
```

The second statement returns nothing while the first highlights that there is a file in /var/run/

What is happening here?

Comment: Did you try removing the error redirection to see if it showed any error?

Comment: Possibly because `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run` - in the first case, you are starting the search from the 'other' side of the symlink, whereas in the latter case, you need to add the `-L` option to follow the link?

Comment: @steeldriver You are right. Care to make this as an answer?

Comment: OK thanks - done. Hope I got the details correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in Ubuntu<sup>1</sup>, `/var/run` is a symbolic link to `/run`

```
$ ls -l /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun 29 14:05 /var/run -> /run
```

The `find` command has two options that control the handling of symbolic links, as noted in the manual page:

```
   -P     Never follow symbolic links.  This  is  the  default  behaviour.

   -L     Follow symbolic links.
```

so when you ran `find /var/ -name reboot-required`, the link was not followed and the file was not found. In contrast, when you ran `find /var/run/ -name reboot-required`, the search was started from the "other side" of the symbolic link (just as if you had executed `find /run -name reboot-required`), and hence the file *was* found.

Adding the `-L` flag should resolve the ambiguity i.e.

```
find -L /var/ -name reboot-required 2>/dev/null
```

[1 ]. In fact, this seems to be mandated by the [Linux FHS 3.0](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s13.html) standard.